# Tomcat throwing error

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

Working on a JSP project. And the tomcat log has been throwing this error. I've no idea where the issue is. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

It seem to be something to do with a filter `CorsFilter` i created. However, when i deleted the servlet, the record disappeared along with it in the web.xml.

```
04-Jan-2018 16:33:55.466 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-123] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception starting filter CorsFilter
 java.lang.ClassCastException: com.reviewmyprof.webservice.book.Book cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Filter
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4583)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:586)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:460)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1586)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor45.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1460)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:906)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:344)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DeleteReview</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.reviewmyprof.webservice.review.DeleteReview</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>my-books</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/my-books.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>book-home</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/book_home.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>submit-book</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/submit_book.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>edit-book</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/edit_book.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ApproveReview</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ApproveReview</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DeleteReview</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/delete-review</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>books</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/books</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>my-books</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/my-books</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>book-home</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/book-home</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>submit-book</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/submit-book</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>edit-book</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/edit-book</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/home.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>contact-us</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/contact-us.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>term-of-use</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/term-of-use.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>faq</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/faq.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>submit-review</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/submit-review.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>submit-request</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/submit-request.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>books</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/books.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>about-us</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/about-us.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>admin</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/admin.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ApproveReview</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.reviewmyprof.webservice.review.ApproveReview</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>submit-review</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/submit-review</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>submit-request</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/submit-request</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>about-us</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/about-us</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>admin</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>contact-us</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/contact-us</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>term-of-use</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/term-of-use</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>faq</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faq</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

CorsFilter was added to web.xml. Has since been removed.

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.reviewmyprof.webservice.book.Book</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
            <param-value>GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
```

Comment: Please add code of CorsFilter

Comment: `com.reviewmyprof.webservice.book.Book` has already been deleted

Comment: So what is the issue now after you deleted CorsFilter and Book class?

Comment: tomcat is still throwing errors non-stop

Comment: @vikarjramun, I've already removed it as mentioned in my post.

Comment: You emptied the content of the work folder of your tomcat before restarting ? Are you using eclipse ?

Comment: @root Try this: delete the war from the Tomcat folder, remove the unpacked folded, and recreate your war then deploy it. Sometimes Tomcat has issues with deployment. If you don't have a CorsFilter, it doesn't make sense that there is a error about it so this must be the issue

Comment: @vikarjramun, I understand that and already tried it. That's what puzzled me too. I'll see if i can figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: @root uhh.... restart Tomcat? Reboot the server? Theoretically this should not have happened